# A question about the lower limit function of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence of functions on (0,2) defined by $f_n (x)=x$ if n is even, and $f_n (x)=2-x$ if n is odd. Then the lower limit f is defined by $f(x)=x$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=2-x$ if $x \in [1,2]$.

I am surprised to see that if change the definition of $f_n$ by swap the even and odd, that is, $f_n (x)=x$ if n is odd, and $f_n (x)=2-x$ if n is even. The lower limit function f is the same. Why it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for any $x$ in $(0,2)$ the sequence $f_n(x)$ takes only two values $2-x$ and $x$, both infinitely many times. So $$\liminf f_n(x) = \sup_{n}\inf_{k\geq n} f_n(x) = \min\left\{2-x,x\right\}$$
Clearly the order in which it takes the two of them doesn't really matter, because what matters for the $\liminf$ is the infimum from a certain time, onwards.

In fact, and think about this, it could be $f_n(x)=x$ for every $n$ but those like $n=2^k$ for some $k$, in which it is $f_n(x)=2-x$.